# geom_point runs from console but not from R Markdown (knit html)

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I have the following dataset

```
head(myDataFrame)
  rating      lat       lon
1    4.0 40.70952 -74.01460
2    3.8 40.70144 -74.01514
3    4.1 40.72795 -74.00139
4    4.1 40.71792 -73.99012
5    4.1 40.72706 -73.98855
6    4.1 40.71568 -74.00849
```

and the following point

```
geo
[1] "40.7127837"        "-74.0059413"       "New York, NY, USA"
```

When I run the following function from the console it runs great

```
showLocationsOnMap <- function(geo,myDataFrame) {
  map <- get_map(location = c( lon =as.numeric(geo[2]), lat = as.numeric(geo[1])), maptype = "satellite", zoom = 14)
  ggmap(map) + geom_point(data = myDataFrame, aes(x=lon, y=lat, color=rating)) + scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rainbow(4))
}
```

but when I run it from the R Markdown I get the following error

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric In addition: Warning messages: 1: package 'RCurl' was built under R version 3.2.4 2: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.2.4 Execution halted

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. Try updating packages maybe...

Comment: It might also help if you copy and paste the whole code chunk.

Comment: ```{r}
showLocationsOnMap <- function(geo,locationsInfo) {
  map <- get_map(location = c( lon =as.numeric(geo[2]), lat = as.numeric(geo[1])), maptype = "satellite", zoom = 14)
  ggmap(map) + geom_point(data = locationsInfo, aes(x=lon, y=lat, color=as.numeric(rating))) + scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rainbow(4))
}
```

Comment: @martin-dabbel-ju-smelter

Comment: What does `class(locationsInfo)`return? Are you sure its a data.frame?

Comment: Yes, it's data.frame and all packages are up to date

Comment: With the data provided above and your code I simply cannot reproduce the error.... :/ I guess the error lies somewhere in your (complete) script.